# Imagick jpg background isn't transparent on rotate

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm currently using imagemagick version ImageMagick 6.8.4-6 2013-04-04 Q16
with Imagick extension version 1620

I am trying to rotate a jpg image and merge this into another jpg image however when i merge the image i get a black box arround the image.

Please see the code i am using below:

```
public function image($images,$x,$y,$angle){

        if($images != "" && $images != NULL){
         $base = $this->instance;
         $layer = new Imagick($images);

         //resize image

         if($this->id == 45){
             $layer->scaleImage(329,0);
         }
         if($this->id == 44){
            $layer->scaleImage(280,0);
         }
         if($this->id == 42){
            $layer->scaleImage(350,0);
         }

         //rotate image

         $layer->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel("none"), $angle);

         //Merge Image
         if($this->id == 44){
          $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y);
         }else{
          $base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $x, $y);
         }

         $this->image = $base;
        }


    }
```

The the test is currently been run when $this->id uses 44.
Can anyone shed light on this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Imagick jpg background isn't transparent on rotate"* You need to use `imagecolortransparent` in order to have transparency capabilities - **N.B.** `JPG` do not have transparent properties, only `PNG` and `GIF` files (and TIFF) but browsers do not support that format. Your output file will need to be converted to one of those formats, preferably `PNG` then set the transparency for the desired color. (*"Worthy as an answer, I'd say."*) ;-)

Comment: *"Can anyone shed light on this issue?"* I did ---^

Comment: @Fred-ii- so would you suggest converting to PNG then rotating? then merging the PNG image into the JPG (if it is possible) as the image output is required to be a jpg

Comment: You would have to, you don't have a choice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for your comment. As you said i don't have a great deal of choice. Thank you. Would you care to write this as an answer?

Comment: You're welcome. I saw your edited comment just now. You will lose transparency as soon as you resave as JPG.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so technically the whole image needs to be converted to a PNG and merged while both are PNG images and then after merging the image convert the png to jpg?

Comment: Just did now, glad I could shed some light on the subject. I've been in the graphic arts industry since the early 90s, so it helps to help others in that field. :)

Comment: *"and then after merging the image convert the png to jpg?"* You could merge both but then you will lose the transparency as soon as it's saved as a `JPG`. There's no getting away from it, unfortunately.

Comment: There may be a jQuery plugin that could do the work for you "after the fact", but I don't recall ever seeing one.

Comment: Yeah these things seem to be a major pain in the back end. I will try and find an alternative solution and post back later

Comment: Someone should have thought about this years ago, thus they came out with `PNG` to offer graphic artists and Web designers that added ability/option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `imagecolortransparent` in order to have transparency capabilities.

**N.B.** `JPG` does not have transparent properties, only `PNG` and `GIF` files (and `TIFF`) but browsers do not support that format.

Your output file will need to be converted to one of those formats, preferably `PNG` then set the transparency for the desired color.

*"so would you suggest converting to PNG then rotating? then merging the PNG image into the JPG (if it is possible) as the image output is required to be a jpg"*

You will lose transparency as soon as you resave as `JPG`

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use imagecolortransparent as this would be an uploaded image which if that color is in the image it will become transparent

Comment: @LiamSorsby Ok, I now see the predicament you're set in. Users uploading may not all have `PNG` files, is that the issue you're faced with?

Comment: yes so basically the image uploaded is currently merged into a jpg background that we have using Imagick. But depending on what sort of image they upload depends on whether transparency is kept. which is why i thought it would be better to convert to png, merge then convert back to jpg

Comment: @LiamSorsby Ok I understand. If you haven't already an `if` condition set depending on the type of file being uploaded, you could probably crop the `JPG`, then have a new layer with a gradient background or a set color with a border then the original `JPG` on top of that, and rotate/merge both from there.

Comment: the only issue with that is it does't change the fact it has to be rotated. which then leaves the nasty pixels which is bazar as it makes a little bit of it transparent but not the rest

Comment: @LiamSorsby Try to "storyboard" <= (animation term but it applies here to think the process through) the way you would like the end results to be, yet keeping in mind that the image won't be transparent and to replace it with a background you can live with. That's the best I can suggest to you. I know it's pain in the neck, but unfortunately, that's the way `JPG` was conceived as, way back when. Nobody knew/thought about how things would be today. *(I worked as an animator for 4 years).*

Comment: With regards to your proposed method to us imagecolortransparent how would you sugest using this with imagick?

Comment: @LiamSorsby I'm not familiar with `ImageMagick` enough to elaborate on the subject. I do all my work in graphics programs. I wish I could help you more on that subject Liam.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this via Google, here's the correct answer as others may find it. You need to use setImageMatte(1) to enable the transparency, e.g.

```
$src->setImageMatte(1); 
$mask->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel('#00000000'), 10);
```

You may also use an image Mask, where black will become transparent using

```
$src->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```